# coroutine.send() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, performance, discord.py

```
async def suggest(ctx, *, suggestion):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    wait(1)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=f"** ✅ {ctx.message.author.mention} Successfully sent your suggestion to our staff team. Thanks for the suggestion!*")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    wait(5)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    # channel = client.get_channel(859879455459770429)  # My channel
    # canel = client.get_channel(861267571915227136)  # azuzu channel
    everyonesChan = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="suggestions")
    if everyonesChan is None:
        everyonesChan = ctx.guild.create_text_channel("suggestions")

    embed = discord.Embed(title="E", colour=0x52b788)
    embed.set_author(
        name=f'Suggested by {ctx.message.author}', icon_url=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
    embed.add_field(name="New Suggestion!", value=f'{suggestion}')
    everyoneMes = await everyonesChan.send(embed=embed)
```

Everytime i say *suggest [something] it sends the "sent" embed and after that i get an error saying  coroutine.send() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  `everyoneMes = await everyonesChan.send(embed)`

Comment: yes thanks and omg holy u got 12k rep. thank you so much uncle!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: ok and holy 100k rep?! THANK U i will!